# Add custom menu item to column menu in angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to add a custom menu item to column menu in ui-grid.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
                    paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
                    paginationPageSize: 25,
                    enablePaginationControls: true,
                    useExternalPagination: true,
                    useExternalSorting: true,
                    enableScrollbars: true,
                    enableColumnMenu: true,
                    enableRowSelection: true,
                    enableSelectAll: true
}
```

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

angular ui-grid provides functionality to  customize the column menu -
[Customizing the Column menu](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu)

I've also created a fiddle which will add customized menu called "Grid Id" for Name column in the Column Menu .

[Check the Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshwar33/ma3g7ava/1/)

```
Add menuItems function to $scope.gridOptions
 menuItems:[{
                title:'Grid Id',
                action: function(){
                         //add your logic here
                    alert('Grid ID: ' + this.grid.id);
                }
            }],
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to globally configure menu items? Your answer seems to imply that, but your Fiddle configures these at the column level. Thanks